# Access Permalink

Tags: orchardcms

Continuing on my quest to learn Orchard and create my first theme, I've overridden Content-BlogPost.

How do I access the link to the full blog post?  I am rendering a list of blog posts and it works great, but I need to be able to link to the full post.

My original thought was:

Model.ContentItem.Permalink.Url, or something similar.  But I know that Permalink does not exist.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Url.ItemDisplayUrl(Model.ContentItem)` should do the trick.